# Correct use of an Incremental Calculation of XGBRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, increment, xgboost

I would like to ask if my implementation of `XGBRegressor` and use of its incremental calculation is correct.

Usually, we would use an incremental approach when we have very huge number of observations.

I have provided an example down bellow:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

np.random.seed(1)

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
# Add an artifical Batch Identificator
df = df.sample(frac = 1)
df['batch'] = np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], repeats=30)
df.head()

param = {'max_depth': 100, 'objective': 'reg:squarederror'}
gbm_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(**param)

y = df['petal_width']
X = df.loc[:, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']]

for i, batch in enumerate(df['batch'].unique()):
    if i == 0:
        X_i = df.loc[df['batch'] == batch, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']]
        y_i = df.loc[df['batch'] == batch, 'petal_width']
        gbm_model.fit(X_i, y_i)
        gbm_model.save_model('gbm_model.model')
        print(f"RMSE: {np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, gbm_model.predict(X)))}")
    if i != 0:
        X_i = df.loc[df['batch'] == batch, ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length']]
        y_i = df.loc[df['batch'] == batch, 'petal_width']
        gbm_model.fit(X_i, y_i, xgb_model = 'gbm_model.model')
        print(f"RMSE: {np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, gbm_model.predict(X)))}")
        gbm_model.save_model('gbm_model.model')
```

As can be observed, the RMSE metric is not decreasing as the model has seen more dataset. This is very curious as it indicates that there might be an error within the code as Incremental learning does not help.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question and just FYI, you don't need `np.sqrt` to get the RMSE - you can simply use `mean_squared_error(squared=False)` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html)). Saves some parentheses and improves readability...

Comment: It seems you are using the iris dataset in an unconventional way (for regression, instead of classification). Do we have reasons to believe that `petal_width` is indeed predictable from the other numerical features? Why not making it a classification problem with `XGBClassifier` instead?

Comment: I have just provided some dataset that allows for regression. We can use another but the question is why the RMSE is not decreasing.